# visual studio cannot open new project

Tags: visual-studio

Whenever I try to create a new project in VS 2010 I get the error:

> New project/item dialog could not be initialized due to error:
>   Exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Dialogs.DialogInitializationException' was thrown.

And when try to open existing project visual studio 2010 restarts.

Comment: Try repairing your installation of Visual Studio, or simply reinstall it.

Comment: i tryied but its not working and i  think i must reinstall the windows

Comment: I am having the exact same problem when I try vs 2013 , new project . Were you able to resolve it ?

Comment: Try running Visual Studio with Admin user.

Answer (score 33):

I had the same problem on my computer. After a long time searching I solved it by the following steps:

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio
2. Go to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE" *(or whatever is your VS installation directory)*
3. Run command `devenv.exe /resetuserdata` and wait until finished
4. Run Visual Studio

Comment: I am facing the same issue on Visual Studio Professional 2015 but I dont have folder IDE inside Common7 as given above "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE".

Comment: Ritesh Gupta, just open Run inteface and insert devenv.exe /resetuserdata                            It works like a magic

Comment: Worked with this .

Comment: Before running this command make sure you go thru this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823385/what-does-visual-studio-devenv-exe-resetuserdata-do-exactly - For me in VS 2019 I just re-launched the VS with admin user and has worked.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find the former case. As you met an exception

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Dialogs.DialogInitializationException

I am suggesting you try the way below:

Run `devenv /resetuserdata`.

Delete the file:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache
```

and restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Close all VS instances and try the solution mentioned [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/30312/problems-when-starting-vs-2017-enterprise-on-windo.html):

- Launch **Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017** as Administrator
- Go to VS 2017 installation folder, for example: `pushd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise`
- `gacutil -if Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0.dll`

Answer (score 0):

Open your control panel
Change

```
Regional -> Formats tab -> Format: English(United States)
```

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/727578/vs-do-not-work-with-finnish-number-format-on-w8-64-bit

It works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem can cause when you install an older version of Visual Studio nearby the current version. For example `VS 2017` is installed on your system and you do force install of `VS 2008`.
I faced this problem many years ago by installing `VS 2008` after `VS 2010`;
and today again I had this problem. Because I installed `SolidWorks 2015` after `VS 2017`. `SolidWorks` had a Visual Studio 2008 inside its package that interferes my installation.
Just uninstalled `VS 2008` and I'm done.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to still be an issue in Visual Studio Community 2017, Microsoft released a work around that fixed my problem:

> The work-around for this issue would be:
>
> -Launch “Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017” as Administrator
>
> -Go to VS 2017 installation folder, for example: pushd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise
>
> -gacutil -if Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0.dll