# Cannot open "Extensions and Updates" in Visual Studio: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm having 2 errors in Visual Studio.

1. I try to open Tools > Extensions and Updates... and get this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

2. When I try to open a new project I get this error:

> New project/item dialog could not be initialized due to error: Exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Dialogs.DialogInitializationException' was thrown.

How do I fix these errors?
pls help me

Comment: Uninstall and re-install?

Comment: @NathanOliver 6 times

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury 2015

Comment: My understanding is the VS 2015 uses .NET so one thing to check is that you have the latest version installed and up to date. What OS are you using? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963241/visual-studio-cannot-open-new-project as well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225637/cant-create-new-projects-nor-items-visual-studio-2010-dialog-initialization-ex

Comment: It will say you cannot delete _some_  of the sub folders.. So go to each sub folder, delete its content and then you will be able to delete the sub folder. So try **force** delete **all** the sub folders and their contents of this folder `C:\Users\ ...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0`. Also "Update 3" for VS just got released, so maybe try updating

Comment: @RichardChambers windows. I see that questions and do what they said there , but it doesn't work